# Filter Cursor type NSPredicate

Tags: android, list, cursor

I need to use NSPredicate on Android, I'll explain why:

I am creating a lot of statistics on data and then do a read-only database of all the data, which gives me a Cursor.

Then I have to filter out many times these data based on different filters, but do not want to do a select query each time, then I would do the operation directly or by cursor or from an array.

What do you advise me to do?

Comment: `but do not want to do a select query each time` why not?

Comment: because more than 1000 or 10000 requests to the db, it would slow down quite a bit

Comment: and you think a filter on an array would be faster ? (not a real question, the answer is no)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure the problem you are solving. Would Apache Commons Collections be helpful?
e.g. filter a list with Predicate?
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/index.html